# Android 12: Mutable or immutable PendingIntent

Tags: marketing-cloud, android, documentation

As per your “[How to Customize Notification Handling](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/notifications/customize-notifications.html)” documentation, one can pass a `PendingIntent` to `SFMCSdk.configure` (or `MarketingCloudSdk.init`) in order to open an `Activity` of choice from the notification. However, it does not mention whether this `PendingIntent` can be immutable or not, and we must [be explicit about this when targeting Android 12](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12?hl=ca#pending-intent-mutability). Will everything work as it should if we pass in a `PendingIntent` with the `PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE` set on it?

Would also appreciate it if this was reflected in the documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: Added the flag to our own implementation in the docs.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may set the intent as `immutable`.  I will pass your documentation comment along.  Thank you.